# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given in ConfusionMatrixDisplay

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, model, forecasting, naivebayes

I create a Model and got an error like this:

[image]

[image]

Previously I changed Confusin_matrix_plot to ConfusinMatrixDisplay but instead got the error above.

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the output of `confusion_matrix` function as input to the `ConfusinMatrixDisplay`.
Example -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import SVC
X, y = make_classification(random_state=0)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,
                                                    random_state=0)
clf = SVC(random_state=0)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = clf.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, predictions, labels=clf.classes_)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm,
                              display_labels=clf.classes_)
disp.plot()

plt.show()
```

[source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html)